# How to configure ocaml ounit tests not to be concurrent?

Tags: ocaml, ounit

Currently I have the following for running my unit tests:

```
let suite = 
  "suite">:::
    ["test_1">:: test_1;
     "test_2">:: test_2;]
;;

let () = 
  run_test_tt_main suite
;;
```

Problem is, test_1 and test_2 involve some TCP communication, and have shared ports. I need them to run sequentially, I don't care what order.

**Edit: command line argument can be specified to run them sequentially**

```
test-name -runner sequential
```

But how do I make this option the default in the source code?

Comment: Apparently, you have to use the old api for sequential tests.

Comment: Oh weird... well I found that I could use a command line argument shortly after posting this, but still would like it to be configured at the level of the source. Also, I'm not quite so sure that the old api isn't capable, there is a sequential_runner defined... In either case, I still don't know how to do it in source.

Comment: Oh...What did you found out exactly? Perhaps you could update your question with what you got so far? That would certainly be helpful...